# Comparing matrix norm with the norm of the inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra

I need help understanding and solving this problem.

> Prove or give a counterexample: If $A$ is a nonsingular matrix, then $\|A^{-1}\| = \|A\|^{-1}$

Is this just asking me to get the magnitude of the inverse of Matrix $A$, and then compare it with the inverse of the magnitude of Matrix $A$?

Comment: It's not true unless the matrix is unitary. Take a simple 2 by 2 matrix and find the norms of A and $A^{-1}$ then see.....

Comment: can you post an example showing how to do this? I'm unsure of how to get the length (double bar) of a matrix?

Comment: Depends on the norm at hand. Try $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @Gary what's your textbook's definition of $\|A\|$ when $A$ is a matrix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A$ is nonsingular, then $AA^{-1} = I$, so

$$ 1 = ||I|| = ||AA^{-1}|| \leqslant ||A||\cdot||A^{-1}||. $$

In general, then $1 \leqslant ||A||\cdot||A^{-1}|| \implies ||A||^{-1} \leqslant ||A^{-1}||$.

Equality is thus not necessarily guaranteed for arbitrary nonsingular $A$; however, the inequality above implies that *equality* may occur. Consider an example.

*Example*:

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}, A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.5 \end{bmatrix} $

$\implies ||A||_{1,2,\infty} = 2$

$\implies ||A^{-1}||_{1,2,\infty} = 1$

$\implies \frac{1}{2} = ||A||_{1,2,\infty}^{-1} \neq ||A^{-1}||_{1,2,\infty} = 1 \implies ||A||^{-1} \neq ||A^{-1}||.$